# Cant copy a tab character from terminal

Tags: terminal

I'm writing a small program that prints to the terminal its output in tab separated format. But whenever I select the text with tabs and copy it, the tabs are replaces with some number of spaces.

What can I do to make terminal not replace tabs with spaces when trying to copy?

Comment: Kurru, I think there is no way!
 There are a ton a questions about this in Stackoverflow and superuser forum. No solution...

Comment: I do some tests. No matter if you use python, shellscript or other language to print the text in the terminal. The result is that it substitutes for spaces.

Comment: I saw more than 10 questions about it... some of : https://superuser.com/questions/687240/how-to-paste-a-tab-into-os-x-terminal-from-clipboard    -     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285925/how-to-copy-tab-delimited-text-to-clipboard-from-within-a-unix-shell-while-prese    -

Answer (score 5):

On macOS Sierra (maybe also in earlier versions), you can do:

```
Edit -> Copy Special -> Copy Plain Text
```

Or using the shortcut: 
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Regular copy works for me. I am on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6. I also have the "Copy Plain Text" option. But any copying of `less`/`more`/`git diff` output converts tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to substitute "\t" in place of tabs in your output, and do a search and replace after you copy and paste it to the destination.
You could use any character or string as the substitute, of course, but using "\t" makes it easy to restore the tabs using *echo -e* if pasting to a command-line environment.
The substitution can be done using: `|sed 's/\\/\\\\\\/g;s/\t/\\t/g'`

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do it on my mac terminal. Here are some good tests:

`printf '>\t<\n'` : works (copies into sublime as a tab; selecting it only lets me select the full tab not individual spaces)

`printf '>\t<\n' | less` : fails

`printf '>\t<\n' | more` : fails

`printf '>\t<\n' | less | cat` : works (less detects output is file/pipe not terminal so no terminal settings applied)

`printf '>\t<\n' | less | cat -vet` : outputs ">^I<$" (less detects pipe output so no terminal settings applied)

`printf '>\t<\n' | vi -` : fails but when I move in vi, it jumps across the tab in 1 keypress so it knows it is a tab

`reset` : from now on, it always fails

`stty -tabs` : from now on, it always fails

`stty tabs` : fixes the `reset`/`stty -tabs` problem, now it can work again

One guy got `less` to work by altering the source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412060/how-to-get-less-to-show-tabs-as-tabs

less related options: '-U' shows tabs as '^I', '-x4' sets tab size

**For `git diff`:**

`git diff | head -40` : works (copies into sublime with tabs)

`git diff | cat` : works

`git diff | less` : fails (less applies terminal settings)

`git diff` : fails (my git pager is less)