# How can I copy tab-delimited text to clipboard from within a unix shell while preserving the tabs?

Tags: parsing, unix, tabs, copy

I am trying to copy and paste a few lines of a file from within a Unix environment into a webpage. I want to preserve the original formatting with disrupting the tabs. However, when I select a block of text and copy and paste it into a webpage, all of the tabs have been converted to various length runs of spaces.

What can I do to preserve the original tabs? It needs to be as simple as possible, so that newbie users can do the same!

Comment: I love tabs too, but I don't see that you're going to be able to come up with technique that will work for 'newbie users' with no telling what kind of software that they use that is installed and don't even know about. Some windowing systems perserve tabs (I'm almost sure), but most convert tabs to spaces permanently. You'd have to add a filter to your copy/paste that was tab-space aware. Finally, sorry, but this isn't a programming question. Try superuser.com or webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. If there are tabs in the text you are copying then it's tabs you'll get. HOWEVER, many text editors have options to convert tabs to spaces, so I'd bet whichever editor you're using is converting the tabs on insert. Which editor (and which terminal emulator) are you using? Exactly how are you selecting, copying and pasting (mouse, then middle click, mouse, crtl+shift+c, crtl+shift+v etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! To clarify, I am using PuTTY on windows. I either view a file in Vim and copy highlighted text, or I `cat` or `head` the file and copy the text from there. In either case, I the text is already devoid of tabs, I can tell when even highlighting the text because the cursor can select each individual space between the words (where the tabs should be). Is there a setting in PuTTY to tell it to preserve these tabs?

Comment: Have you found a way to do that?

Comment: Is on the PuTTY wishlist: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/paste-fidelity.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the text that you're copying is missing the tabs, I suspect that the ptty you're using has converted them for you.  I suspect if you run "stty tabs", you may get the behavior you're looking for (by disabling tab expansion in the ptty).

Comment: Seems (based on comments under the question) that they're using PuTTY (an SSH tool for Windows)... just for context.  That said, when I try doing `stty tabs` when using Tilix on an Ubuntu box, and then do `echo -e '\ttest'` and try selecting the text before `test`, I can tell even while selecting that it's getting spaces.  It seemed promising, but it doesn't seem to work where I'm at, anyway.  Not voting either way, because maybe it'll work somewhere, and I can't test it.  Just adding information.